# Apple push notifications are no longer received

Tags: ios, cordova, ios5, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

We released our phonegap application about a week back and everything was tested and working fine. Fast forward a few days and suddenly people start to report that they aren't receiving any push notifications. I go back to my test devices and fail to reproduce the error for a time but all of a sudden my device just stops receiving them.

I've gone on a debugging spree to try and identify the issue. I stepped through the server side code to ensure that the PushSharp code is being used correctly. I've checked the database to ensure that the user has an up-to-date device token and now I'm going though the steps listed here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

When I enabled logging and sent a push notification a log was created with the appropriate timestamp so I know that SOMETHING happened. However, I'm still not receiving a pop-up on the interface and I can't see anything in the log that suggests it's gone awry.

Here is a pastebin of the log I extracted.

http://pastebin.com/KiCJEsDs

If this doesn't help is there anything else I can do to help identify the issue?

Comment: know it's common but, just check in device setting, notification center, check you application status.

Comment: Everything seems to be enabled, I already tried disabling and re-enbaling.

Comment: are you using your (valid) production certificate and not development certificate? (we've all been there)

Comment: Yup. The certificate states it's type as "APNs Production iOS".